# Thymeleaf : Getting value from a map while iterating through a list

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm trying to get the value from a map while iterating through a list. `searchResult` contains a list of `Book` objects and each has a list of categories.
`categoryFacetCounts` is a map that contains counts for each category value. The map has values for all the possible categories (I debugged and checked).

Below is my solution which prints `null` as the output of the map:

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="watchlist-table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Categories</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr th:each="book : ${searchResult}">
        <td th:text="${book.name}"></td>
        <td th:text="${book.description}"></td>
        <td>
            <span th:each="c : ${book.categories}">
                <span th:text="${c} + '(' + ${categoryFacetCounts[__${c}__]} + ') '"></span>
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `get` method of the map, `categoryFacetCounts`

```html
<span th:each="c : ${book.categories}">
       <span th:text="${c} + '(' + ${categoryFacetCounts.get(c)} + ') '"></span>
</span>
```

Hope this helps.